# Memory management of Android devices

Tags: storage

According to manufacturer, my phone has:

- ROM-4 GB
- RAM-1 GB

But when I look in my phone, there is

1. PHONE STORAGE(.98 GB)
2. INTERNAL MEMORY(1.77 GB)

Now is that .98+1.77 from those 4 GB (ROM memory) – or from where? And what is the difference between this phone storage (.98 gb) and internal memory (1.77gb)?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts – and congrats, you've found the correct tag for that question!

Now a little magic which is not that obvious (and thus often overlooked): Hover your mouse over the tag, it will reveal a short description and some links. Click on the [info](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info) link, and find your answer :)

In short here: When manufacturers speak of "ROM", they quite often use this term in a wrong way. The correct meaning of the term is [Read-only memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory), which is clearly not the case for those 4 GB. What they rather are is the all-over storage contained in the device: system (read-only) + internal + device storage. For details, please see the already mentioned [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info).

Manufacturers use the term ROM in a wrong way to show off with "big numbers", unfortunately – which causes a lot of confusion amongst customers.